# How to cut evenly spaced uniform holes in a plate of metal?

Tags: machining, cnc

I've looked everywhere for this seemingly simple question, but I cannot for the life of me find out how to easily cut a specific amount of holes in a plate of metal with my cnc. Am I going to have to make each individual hole, or is there a program that automatically generates an svg, g-code, stl, etc. for evenly spaced holes?

I'm attempting to cut a grid pattern using a Shapeoko and a Grbl Arduino shield.

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to arrange holes so that they are "evenly spaced" - what configuration in particular are you talking about? A line, a regular grid, a hex grid, etc.

Comment: We need more information. What type of CNC and CNC Controller do you have? Most commercial/industrial controllers offer this feature built into the controller to create a hole pattern with an existing canned hole cycle. Otherwise, depending on how many holes you have, you could probably write a simple macro yourself or use notepad to create the code. Also, are those canned drilling  cycles available on your controller? Otherwise, you might need to make your own drilling macro as well.

Comment: Unless you have some CAM software, your best bet would be to write some VBA macro for excel to generate your gcode.